# Htaccess, redirect if folder exists

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect the user if the folder install exists but i had no luck so far.

Below is my htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /enc/project/
# If the setup directory exists in the document root...
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/install -d
# ...and you're not in isntall..
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(install) [NC]
# ...redirect to setup - with a 302 (temporary redirect) to make sure the browser won't cache the redirect.
RewriteRule ^(.*) /install [L,redirect=302]
# ...rest of htaccess for codeigniter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

The codeigniter project is in the `/enc/project/` in my server thats why the RewriteBase.

```
Project Structure is

htdocs/enc/project/
|-- application/
|   |-- project
|
|-- system/
|   |-- project
|
|-- install/
|   |-- test/
|   |   |-- test_main.php
|   |   
|   |-- index.php
|
|-- htaccess
```

Comment: `localhost/enc/project`

Comment: i edited the question with my project structure

Comment: i'll give it a try now and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Yes problem is with this one though that i get a blank page and redirects every css request or file i'm trying to load to the install folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /enc/project/

# If the setup directory exists in the document root...
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/enc/project/install -d
# ...and you're not in isntall..
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# ...redirect to setup - with a 302 (temporary redirect) to make sure the browser won't cache the redirect.
RewriteRule !^install/ install/ [L,NC,R=302]

# ...rest of htaccess for codeigniter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of writing it that works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /enc/project/
# If the setup directory exists in the document root...
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/enc/project/install -d
# ...and you're not in isntall..
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(install) [NC]
# ...redirect to setup - with a 302 (temporary redirect) to make sure the browser won't cache the redirect.
RewriteRule ^(.*) /enc/project/install/ [L,redirect=302]
# ...rest of htaccess for codeigniter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Yes problem is with this one though that i get a blank page and redirects every `css` request or file i'm trying to load to the install folder